# Why wont this work (ArrayList in java)?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to make a snake game, for that I used an ArrayList to store each individual Point object that makes the snake. The following code creates the snake:

```
private void createSnake() {
    for (int i = 0; i < maxLenght; i++) {
        snakeParts.add(new Point(head.x, head.y + (i * 16)));
    }

}
```

maxLenght is set to 3 by default, and this code is only called once; what i want it to do is create 3 Point objects in the upper left corner in a column, representing the first three parts of the snake, but for some reason, either it only creates one in the upper left corner or creates all three, but in the same position, how can I make it work?

Note: i am using the Timer render method so this is supposed to happen a lot every second(?), if not what render method could I use?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: This is the Snake class's Constructor

```
public ArrayList<Point> snakeParts;
public Point head;

public Snake() {
    snakeParts = new ArrayList<Point>();
    head = new Point(0, 0);

    curDir = 1;

    createSnake();

}
```

EDIT 2: This is the render class

```
public class Renderer extends JPanel {

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, Core.frame.getWidth(), Core.frame.getHeight());

    Snake snake = new Snake();
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    for (Point point : snake.snakeParts) {
        g.fillRect(snake.head.x, snake.head.y, 16, 16);
    }
}
```

Comment: When you step through you code in your debugger, is `maxLenght` what your expected it to be?  I suspect it is always `1`.

Comment: What do you mean by does not work? See any exception ? Adding more details would be helpful in getting answers.

Comment: Could you provide more code to look into it? How are you declaring and defining your 'Point' constructor and Arraylist<Point>?

Comment: @PeterLawrey If you mean the size of the ArrayList, already checked it, it IS 3

Comment: @Sachin I mean, as i said I want to see the three Points in a column, but it only shows one Point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your render method is

```
for (Point point : snake.snakeParts) { 
   g.fillRect(snake.head.x, snake.head.y, 16, 16); 
}
```

So you are drawing the same Rectangle for each point.

correct would be:

```
for (Point point : snake.snakeParts) { 
  g.fillRect(point.x, point.y, 16, 16);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved it! What a dumb mistake by me :S